# Creating a table in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to make a table that will take two entries and also store the date of those entries

```
$sql="CREATE TABLE Practice(Title TEXT, Body TEXT, Date DATETIME)";
```

I create the table successfully and can add entries to title and body but when it comes to the date i get this error

```
Error: Incorrect datetime value: 'March 20th 2014' for column 'Date' at row 1
```

This is my code for adding the datetime

```
$date = new DateTime('');
$savedate = $date->format('F jS Y');
$sql="INSERT INTO Practice(Title, Body, Date)
VALUES
('$_POST[title]','$_POST[body]','$savedate')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";
```

Is the way i'm formatting my datetime wrong? and if so how do i fix it?

Thanks

Comment: The format should be: `Y-m-d`

Comment: You're using wrong format.

Answer (score 0):

From https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html

> The DATE type is used for values with a date part but no time part.
>   MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. The
>   supported range is '1000-01-01' to '9999-12-31'.
>
> The DATETIME type is used for values that contain both date and time
>   parts. MySQL retrieves and displays DATETIME values in 'YYYY-MM-DD
>   HH:MM:SS' format. The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to
>   '9999-12-31 23:59:59'.

So, **YYYY-MM-DD** is what you want.

Comment: When i do this i get
`Error: Incorrect datetime value: '2014201420142014-MarMar-ThuThu 1212:MarMar:thth' for column 'Date' at row 1`

Comment: when I say YYY-MM-DD it is not a php date format, it is mysql, which means year with 4 digits, month 2, day 2.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write in the date of the position `now ()`

Comment: Or maybe add TIMESTAMP field NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP